# NetSuite searchMoreWithID fails with Invalid SOAP action

Tags: soap, netsuite

I'm trying to extend my NetSuite search beyond the 100 item limit.  I'm using SOAP through zeep in a python app but I'm testing in Postman first.  I can successfully get the first page of the search using a **CustomRecordSearchAdvanced**.  However, when I use the nsid from the response in the follow on **searchMoreWithId** request I am getting the following error

```
        <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Invalid SOAPAction header: Search</faultstring>
```

The SOAP header is exactly the same in both cases.  The SOAP body for the first search which works is

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <search xsi:type='platformMsgs:SearchRequest'>
        <searchRecord xsi:type='setupCustom:CustomRecordSearchAdvanced' savedSearchId='1234'/>
    </search>
</soapenv:Body>
```

The SOAP body for the second search which fails is below.  I copy the searchId exactly from the response of the first search.

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <searchMoreWithId xsi:type='platformMsgs:SearchMoreWithIdRequest'>
        <searchId xsi:type='xsd:string'>WEBSERVICES_************</searchId>
        <pageIndex xsi:type='xsd:int'>2</pageIndex>
    </searchMoreWithId>
</soapenv:Body>
```

The WSDL I am using is https://webservices.na1.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2020_1_0/netsuite.wsdl and from what I can tell, this should work although there is no section in the WSDL with SOAP actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message inside the SOAP Fault is:

> Invalid SOAPAction header: Search

Looking at the WSDL, the header value should be `searchMoreWithId` not `Search`.

You can find the value to use for the `SOAPAction` header inside each `<soap:operation>` of the WSDL. The name of the operation you are requesting needs to match with an appropriate header. You are making a request to `searchMoreWithId` with a `Search` header, and from here your error message. Change the header value to `searchMoreWithId` and try again.

Note also that the `SOAPAction` header is [a HTTP header, not a SOAP header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445400/soap-headers-versus-http-headers/).

Comment: That's brilliant - all is working - thanks!  I'd not connected the changes in the body from search to searchMoreWithId to a required change in the SOPAAction in the http header.  Now I just need to work out how to make zeep do the same thing.